# Xamarin Forms MSAL and AAD authentication problem with Device ID

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We are implementing application, that should confirm our internal processes. We are using Azure AD and we would like to make this app only for company purposes. So we would like to have it managed by InTune.

When we start application, we are redirect to mobile browser where is MS authentication form and if we have success logg in, then their API check whether is the mobile enrolled under company management profile, if yes return to app otherwise end up with warnign only for company purposes.

The problem is that despite we have endrolled mobile their API does not recognize it and can´t proceed. In the error description is that the mobile is not regeistered and the Device ID is null, but when we check device under AZURE portal we can see that the device has logged Device ID and is correctly enrolled. And in list of access to this application we can see log, where is login failed (missing Device ID).

This problem occures only on android, not with iOS. In case of iOS is everything OK.

Could not be the problem with reading this device ID from mobile? In iOS, we set up access to KeyChainAccess with microsoft.adalcache. Does exist anything like that in Android?

I have go throught this tutorial: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: MSAL does not currently work with broker (authenticator app or Intune company portal), this is a feature that is in the works and should be available in the coming months. This works on iOS because of keychain sharing, and shared preferences on Android does not work the same, so some type of token broker (authenticator app) would be needed.

Comment: So I dont understand why in official git AZURE samples is noticed implementation for android and UWP. Ok, do you have any idea how to implement login over AAD and be sure, that InTune is installed on device?

Comment: Hi @Jenny Has this feature been implemented yet.  Just to confirm, MSAL.js does not work with Microsoft Intune Browser.  It will work with all other mobile browsers.